# How do I inspect the last good layer from a failed Docker build?

Tags: docker

I've seen lots of examples on the web that claim it's possible to inspect a layer from a failed Docker build using something like `docker run -it $LAYER_ID`. However, the examples involve getting `$LAYER_ID` from the output of `docker build`, and my version of Docker isn't printing layer ID's during build.

`docker build` is producing output like this, with no ID's printed for the layers:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gcc:5.5.0                            0.2s
 => FROM docker.io/library/lightda-examples-src:latest                                  0.0s
 => CACHED FROM docker.io/library/lightda_lenkf_rsm-repo:latest                         0.0s
 => FROM docker.io/library/hdf5_exceptions-repo:latest                                  0.0s
 => FROM docker.io/library/lightda-repo:latest                                          0.0s
 => FROM docker.io/library/fortran_exceptions-repo:latest                               0.0s
 => FROM docker.io/library/system_mpi-repo:latest                                       0.0s
 => https://download.open-mpi.org/release/open-mpi/v4.1/openmpi-4.1.0.tar.bz2           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 65B                                                        0.0s
 => [build_base 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/gcc:5.5.0@sha256:207a4645d46ee2eae62500c6c  0.0s
 => CACHED [build_base 2/6] RUN if command -v apt-get; then apt-get update; fi          0.0s
 => CACHED [build_base 3/6] RUN if command -v apt-get; then apt-get -y install cmake g  0.0s
 => CACHED [build_base 4/6] RUN if command -v yum; then yum -y install cmake git; fi    0.0s
 => CACHED [build_base 5/6] RUN useradd --home-dir /build build                         0.0s
 => CACHED [build_base 6/6] WORKDIR /build                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [build_with_ford 1/3] RUN if command -v apt-get; then apt-get install -y li  0.0s
 => CACHED [build_with_ford 2/3] RUN if command -v yum; then yum -y install lapack-dev  0.0s
 => CACHED [build_with_ford 3/3] RUN pip3 install fprettify ford                        0.0s
```

This is a different format than shown in examples on the web, and also different from what I've seen before from Docker (FWIW, I'm on MacOS currently, and my previous experience with Docker was on Linux). How do I get Docker to print layer ID's and then execute the last good layer from a filed build for debugging?

Comment: It looks like you're using the [`buildx` driver](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/). When using buildx, the easiest solution is just to comment out everything in the Dockerfile from the failing command onwards, and then examine the resulting image.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. I was hoping there was something better but apparently buildx/BuildKit doesn't currently provide a way to inspect/debug individual build stages (see https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1472).